# javascript remove attribute submit field not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like to change the attribute of a submit button based on the value of the variable

```
            var var123 = document.getElementById('elementId').value;
            if(var123=='')
            {
                $('form#elementId').submit(function(e){
                    $(this).children('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                    return false;
                });
            } else {

                $('form#elementId').submit(function(e){
                   alert(var123); $(this).children('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                    return false;
                });
            }
```

when the value of var is NULL the button has to be disables.
when the value of var is different from NULL the submit button should be clickable again.

The code disable the button but does not allow the click again.
Seems that prop('disabled', false) is not executed.

The html code is:

```
    echo "<form action='download.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='elementId'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='title' id='title' placeholder='Title'>";

.....

echo "<input class='sendButton' type='submit' value='send'></form>";
```

can someone please help me ?

Comment: Uh, there is no PHP in this question.

Comment: When is this block of code run? Is it within an event handler?

Comment: `var var` doesn't even run in JS. You can't use var as an identifier.

Comment: please show the html code

Comment: I had to chose 5 tags :(

Comment: yes the code is inside an event handler and executed every 3 seconds

Comment: You're aware that your disable/enable toggle is also further within a handler for the form submit, right?  So if the button you're disabling is the button that submits the form, how are you going to submit the form after that to trigger the handler again?

Comment: the content of var is actually the value of the field input type='text'. I would like to disable the send button until this field is set with a value by the user.

Comment: @MissCube  Please only show us your _actual_ code, not something that may or may not be particularly representative of it.

Comment: "I would like to disable the send button until this field is set with a value by the user"  So put a `change` handler (or maybe a `blur` handler) on that field and put your toggle in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as your input submit button has *class='sendButton'*, Try like this:

```
$('form#formSubmit').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var val = document.getElementById('elementId').value;
    if(val === ''){
        $('.sendButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }else{
        $('.sendButton').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

var is keyword of javascript so change the name i have change it val try following code :

```
var val = document.getElementById('elementId').value;
    if(val=='')
    {
        $('form#formSubmit').submit(function(e){
            $(this).children('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
            e.preventDefault(); 
            return false;
        });
    } else {
        $('form#formSubmit').submit(function(e){
            $(this).children('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
            e.preventDefault(); 
            return false;
        });
    }
```

Comment: did you change name of variable var ??

Comment: yes i changed the name of var into var123. I added an alert. The alert is executed every 3 seconds but the buttn is not clickable also with your code prop('disabled', false);

Comment: use this it should work  : $(this).children('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled", false);

Answer (score -2):

Try .removeProp('disabled') instead.